# How can i download map tiles in android from Google MAP?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to download map tiles from Google MAP.
But I don't have any way to make that.
Please answer my question .
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way i used with OpenWeatherMap to add weather tiles to google map.
You have to create a TileProvider:

```
private TileProvider createTilePovider() {
    TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
        @Override
        public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            String fUrl = String.format(OWM_TILE_URL, tileType == null ? "clouds" : tileType, zoom, x, y); // This is the OWM url you can use yours
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(fUrl);
            }
            catch(MalformedURLException mfe) {
                mfe.printStackTrace();
            }

            return url;
        }
    } ;
```

If you created a Google Map Activity with Android studio you have a method called setUpMaps(), write in it:

```
tileOver = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(createTileProvider()));
```

In this case it is used UrlTileProvider because we get the tiles from the URL.
Be aware of the tiles opacity.

If you want to have more info give a look [at my blog](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/03/android-google-map-add-weather-data-tile.html).
Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download the Google Tiles, you are not allowed to do it from the licensing terms of Google Maps API.

If you want to download custom tiles instead, it depends on which is the source from which you want to get data